# React Router V6 UseContextApi: object null is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

I am having a small problem with my code.

So, this is the first time I am trying to implement context on a project but I am getting an error:

### Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

I guess is because the object is not being accessed by the child component.

Here is the parent component (My Routes)

```
import {UserContext} from "../Context/UserContext"

function WebRoutes() {
  const [user,setUser]=useState(null);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={(user,setUser)}>
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login/>}/>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route path="/departaments" element={<Departaments/>}/>
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product/>}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
        </Routes>
    </Router>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

This one will be the child component:

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import {UserContext} from '../../Context/UserContext';

const [user,setUser]=useContext(UserContext)
```

That's the way I am trying to get the context.

I am not sure where I am wrong.

This is the UserContext file:

```
import {createContext} from "react"

export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

I would appreciate any kind of help. I am trying to achieve this by using a course.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

```
value={(user, setUser)}
```

You are providing the context value incorrectly as a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) result.

> The **comma operator** (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left
> to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

This means you are providing ***only*** the `setUser` function as the context value.

## Solution

If you are expecting the `UserContext` to return an array:

```
const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
```

Then you should provide an array value:

```
function WebRoutes() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}> // <-- array
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/departaments" element={<Departaments />} />
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```